# Android Emoji Keyboard

Tags: android, emoji

I have to provide smiley keyboard within my Android application. 
For this I am using the following library:
https://github.com/rockerhieu/emojicon

Now, my problem is that I don't understand how to get the edit text value which contains the smileys. As by getting this value I have to store it onto the server side.(I have used PHP service for it.)

I want uni code value for each icon while I am able to get uni code value only for 1 to 10 numbers.

Please help me.

Comment: Have a look at this project: https://github.com/madhur/android-chat-starter